# Who is this strangely named Certificate Authority?

Tags: tls, certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority

I'm researching certificate authorities, and I just have no idea what to think of the CA named

```
x00Ax00-x00Tx00rx00ux00sx00tx00 x00Gx00ex00sx00.x00 x00fx00xFCx00rx00 x00Sx00ix00cx00hx00ex00rx00hx00ex00ix00tx00sx00sx00yx00sx00tx00ex00mx00ex00 x00ix00mx00 x00ex00lx00ex00kx00tx00rx00.x00 x00Dx00ax00tx00ex00nx00vx00ex00rx00kx00ex00hx00rx00 x00Gx00mx00bx00H
```

as indicated in the [EFF observatory](https://www.eff.org/observatory) color [CA map](https://www.eff.org/files/colour_map_of_CAs.pdf).  Google'ing comes up with nothing. Is this an encoding of a name or something? Not that I have seen the certificate on my system or trusted by Chrome. I'm just very curious what it is and where it comes from and why is it encoded/displayed like this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This looks like a poorly encoded name which was even more poorly decoded and reencoded.

Initially, the name seems to be: `A-Trust Ges. für Sicherheitssysteme im elektr. Datenverkehr GmbH`

The name was then encoded in big-endian [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16). In this case, this means that every character yielded two bytes, the first of which having value 0.

Upon decoding, whatever did the decoding failed to recognize the string as UTF-16 (maybe it was wrongly tagged in the certificate; an UTF-16 string should be `BMPString` but some cases of UTF-16 stuffed in `TeletexString` have been spotted in the wild; see the [X.509 style guide](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/x509guide.txt) for more about it). The string was decoded as if it was ASCII, with "invalid" bytes represented with the C-style convention of "`\x`" followed by two hexadecimal characters. This sequence is used in the C programming language to insert explicit byte values in literal strings. Therefore, the initial "`A-T`" became "`\x00A\x00-\x00T`". Similarly, "`für`" became "`\x00f\x00\xFC\x00\xr`" because "ü" is not an ASCII character, and has value 0xFC (aka 252) in Unicode.

When printing out the string, a further injury was inflicted on that string, namely the wholesale removal of all backslash characters. This yielded the exact string that you observe.

(Note that the EFF "CA map" shows other examples of this "C-style without backslashes" representation, e.g. "`SCEE - Sistema de CertificaxE7xE3o ElectrxF3nica do Estado`", which really should be "SCEE - Sistema de Certificação Electrónica do Estado".)

---

Now a simple Googling points to, indeed, a commercial German CA called [A-Trust](https://www.a-trust.at/). Now the mystery deepens a bit, because the CA Web site uses a certificate issued by the CA itself, and the root CA uses the name: `A-Trust Ges. f. Sicherheitssysteme im elektr. Datenverkehr GmbH`, which is correctly encoded in the certificate (as an `UTF8String`), but is not *exactly* the one you observe: the "`für`" has been replaced with "`f.`".

My guess is that what you see is a previous version of the root CA certificate from that CA, and it had encoding problems, which were "solved" by changing the text into something which is pure ASCII. I.e., instead of fixing their software to handle non-ASCII characters properly, they sidestepped the issue. That's kind of sloppy.

Comment: Seriously, though, I have some rather long experience of programming, so I tend to know what kind of mishap can happen with string encodings. Here, I saw the repeated "x00" which I recognized as a descendent of C notation, and the rest was easy.

Comment: Well hopefully I'll be able to program/learn crypto efficiently enough to recognize such things

Comment: Cool! I think the map I was looking at is from 2010 (didn't search for a more up to date one) which explains the rename.